# Deleted the system reserved partition and now I can't boot from a Windows Install DVD

Tags: windows-8, system-reserved-partition

I have a HP laptop. I upgraded to windows 7 ultimate from home basic. Now I'm trying to upgrade to Windows 8 but when I do I get a message saying not enough system partition. So I opened the disk manager and increased the size of system reserved partition and it was of no use I still got the same error.

Then I unfortunately deleted the 100MB system reserved partition by right clicking it and clicking format in the disk manager!

Now I am not able to boot any CD's from the startup including OS and recovery CD. Whenever I press <kbd>esc</kbd> it always goes to the login screen and it doesn't say anything about the boot from CD option. Now I could not even use my recovery CD.

I have 3 questions:

- Is it necesseary to create a system reserved partition if so how to create it?
- How to use my recovery cd
- How to install win 8

Comment: By posting such low-quality questions, you're needlessly generating work for other people. Take the time to write proper sentences (using real words) and format your post properly. "....." is not a valid substitute for a full stop.

Comment: Arun, I'm afraid your question is so vast you will be better off to delete it, and asking only 2 questions. To answer question 2, use Google!

Answer (score 1):

System partition is not required for booting from DVD. You are not setting boot option properly in BIOS. Go read motherboard manual and set BIOS boot order properly. Then do startup repair from DVD.

For other 2 questions, see Google.